# How do you get Yate to launch on startup?

Tags: command-line, startup

How do you make Yate (VoIP telephony) start automatically at startup?

I've read this excellent post about [adding Startup Applications on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login), what I'd like to know is the startup command for Yate specifically.

Add Startup Program (Ubuntu 14.04):

[image: Screenshot: Add Startup Program (Ubuntu 14.04)]

Bonus point if you can offer a link to a list of common startup application commands!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if you are able to give the bonus point with one point rep :), but the command for `yate` is:

```
yate-qt4
```

The commands for globally installed (GUI) applications are found in their corresponding `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`. It is hard to say what are "common" applications, but you can simply open the (any) file in there (drag it over an opened `gedit` window) and look for the *first* line, starting with `Exec=`, followed by the command you are looking for.

#### OR

You can use a script to read all relevant `.desktop` files for you and find the command in it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

dr = "/usr/share/applications"
for f in [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]:
    try:
        s = open(dr+"/"+f).read()
        if not "NoDisplay=true" in s:
            command = [l.split("=")[-1] for l in s.splitlines() if l.startswith("Exec=")][0]
            print(f, "|", command)
    except:
        pass
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `search_commands.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/search_commands.py
  ```

It wil list all commands of GUI applications, globally installed, looking like:

```
...
guake.desktop | guake
xmind.desktop | XMind
gnome-terminal.desktop | gnome-terminal
idle-python2.7.desktop | /usr/bin/idle-python2.7
xfce4-screenshooter.desktop | xfce4-screenshooter
yate-qt4.desktop | yate-qt4
indicator-multiload.desktop | indicator-multiload
...
```

As you can see, `yate-qt4.desktop | yate-qt4` mentions the command you are looking for is `yate-qt4`

Comment: Yes! `yate-qt4` does the trick and your solution for outputting the complete list of Ubuntu startup commands is **really** helpful! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm trying to teach you how to fish instead of giving you just a fish, so bear with me for a moment here.

So you have installed `yate`, probably with `sudo apt-get install yate` but then you don't know the command for it ( which is actually is . . .`yate` . . .very anticlimactic . . . ). Well, there's a method to it.

What you install with `sudo apt-get install yate` is a *package* named `yate`, but then there is actual executable file called `yate`. In this case it's easy - they're named the same. It's a bit more tricky when package and command are different, e.g. `nm-tool` is a command,but it belongs to `network-manager` package.

Why is this important ? Every package installed with `apt-get` uses `dpkg` as  back-end , and in the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` folder we have `*.list` files per each package. `yate` also has one: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/yate.list` There you have list of all the files that `yate` package installs onto your computer, *including the actual command/executable*. Knowing that typically  executables go into `/usr/bin` folder , we conclude that `/usr/bin/yate` is the actual command. You can double check that by calling it form terminal.  So that's the command you want to put as autostart entry.

As for typical autostart entries . . .there is no typical ones, but Ubuntu does have some default autostart entries  (which are hidden by default), in `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder

Comment: This is interesting, though didn't solve the Yate startup issue - the command `yate` doesn't start the application. It's since been correctly answered by @Jacob-Vlijm.